# Install android studio on mac m1 pro, get error "Cannot connect to already running IDE instance"

Tags: macos, android-studio, apple-m1

I'm installing android-studio on a MacBook Pro with Apple M1 chip.

- macOS version: Sonoma 14.2.1
- android-studio version: android-studio-2023.1.1.28-mac_arm.dmg

After installation, got this error when I try to open android-studio:

```
Cannot connect to already running IDE instance.
CannotActivateException: /Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2023.1
```

I don't find any running process with similar name.
And I don't have "AndroidStudio2023.1" in folder "/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/Google/".

I didn't see this error on my previous mac pro with intel chip.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by update the owner of ~/Library/Application Support/Google folder

try sudo chown $USER ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google